# SP_EXECUTESQL with database as variable in from clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to pass parameter into sp_executesql to determine the source of my query? The goal here is to recieve db name as parameter and sql text with placeholder as parameter and combine them together. I can use REPLACE probably but then I won't get the parameter safety check.

Code:

```
DECLARE @my_db VARCHAR(30) = 'MyDatabase'
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'select top 10 * from @db.dbo.table1'


exec sys.sp_executesql @stmt = @sql, @params = N'@db varchar(120)', @db = @my_db;
```

Result:

> Incorrect syntax near '.'.

I'm using SQL Server 2016

Comment: you can't use database or table name as variable. You need to replace it with actual value when you form the dynamic query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You, sort of, can parametrise the database name here. Instead, define the proc name as a variable:

```
DECLARE @DBName sysname = N'MyDatabase';
DECLARE @Proc nvarchar(500) = QUOTENAME(@DBName) + N'.sys.sp_executesql';
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbo.table1 ORDER BY SomeColumn;'; --You need an ORDER BY for reliable results


EXEC @Proc @SQL;
```

The alternative would be to inject the database name into the SQL:

```sql
DECLARE @DBName sysname = N'MyDatabase';
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@DBName) + N'.dbo.table1 ORDER BY SomeColumn;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

For something as simple as you have, I'd actually suggest the former, as there's no injection into the statement, so you avoid SQL injection avenues. If a user entered an invalid database name, you'd just get the following error:

> Msg 911, Level 16, State 4, Line 6
> Database 'abc' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Comment: The alternative won't work since @SQL is received as parameter, only with REPLACE which I don't want to use. The first solution works for me. Thank you.